# Helm for anything

Tags: helm

I use Helm for switching between buffers, opening files, m-x'ing, etc. Is there a way to make helm search in all these things at the same time?

I'd like a super-helm to provide all the results I'd individually have to get from:

- Helm M-x
- Helm find files
- helm-recentf
- helm-buffer-list
- C-u org-refile (so not for refiling, but for jumping to any header)
- and maybe even describe-variable

A little bit like helm-mini already combines Helm find-files and helm-recentf.

It would work like MacOS's Spotlight, i.e. I just start this super-helm command and it searches and narrows on all these sources.

As you type, it would mix results from these sources but make clear from which of these sources the individual hit is.

Comment: Look up how a Helm source is constructed. Try making your own toy helm source for practice. If you know how a helm source works then you can look up the source codes of all the sources you listed and combine them into a single helm command.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom - That is a great suggestion. I'd like to address this at the right level of abstraction though. `helm-mini` allows you to add (I think file-specific) pre-configured `helm-source`'s. My question relates to different items than just files, though. I cannot find in `helm`'s documentation any reference to a command or facility that allows combining the sources in the question on the highest level of abstraction. If not possible, combining parts of the source code of these core `helm` functions might be the only way to go.

Comment: Try opening an issue on Helm github and asking the maintainer in it if there is a facility to combine existing sources.